# Plot the Graph with Dataframe with decreasing and increasing value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have dataframe like this:

```
Date Qty
2021-06-17  60
2021-06-17  -11
2021-06-18  -5
2021-06-19  -2
2021-06-20  20
2021-06-23  -8
2021-06-24  7
2021-06-25  -4
2021-06-26  2
2021-06-29  1
2021-06-30  8
```

**What I need**
I need to plot like this graph, decreasing when the 'qty' number is negative and increasing when it is positive

[image]

**What I got**
The code below is what I got so far.
I have no clue how to plot like I want
[image]

How can I achieve with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continuously sum up the values with the `cumsum` function

```
In [6]: df2 = df.set_index('Date').cumsum()
Out[6]: 
            Qty
Date           
2021-06-17   60
2021-06-17   49
2021-06-18   44
2021-06-19   42
2021-06-20   62
2021-06-23   54
2021-06-24   61
2021-06-25   57
2021-06-26   59
2021-06-29   60
2021-06-30   68
```

This gives you the values you wanted. To plot you just say

```
df2.plot()
```

or and tune the visualisation to your preference :)

[image]

Comment: my x axis shows with over-layered dates, do you know why?

Comment: This could happen because your datatype is string instead of datetime. Then pandas thinks the dates are categorical labels and tries to plot all of them. Try `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])`. If that is not it, I would guess someone on stackoverflow already asked that question before :D

Answer (score 1):

- your **Qty** column is effectively a *delta*.  Just `cumsum()` it and you get what you want
- have included both lines for demonstration purposes.  Clearly no need to plot *Qty*

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Date Qty
2021-06-17  60
2021-06-17  -11
2021-06-18  -5
2021-06-19  -2
2021-06-20  20
2021-06-23  -8
2021-06-24  7
2021-06-25  -4
2021-06-26  2
2021-06-29  1
2021-06-30  8"""), sep="\s+")

df.assign(value=df["Qty"].cumsum()).plot()
```

[image]

Using your code fragment, where dataframe is built from data you pasted:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df_with_index = df.assign(value=df["Qty"].cumsum()).set_index("Date")

ax = df_with_index.loc["2021-06":"2021-07","value"].plot(marker="o",linestyle="-")
ax.set_ylabel("Sales")
```

Comment: I highly recommend [`pd.read_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) :)

Comment: that assumes you have data on clipboard :). generally answering SO questions I find beginners find it simpler if there are no prerequisites to run a code fragment .... i.e. data is on clipboard when you run a code fragment

Comment: Good point. I might start including the setup into my answers as well. At least for beginner questions this will probably never hurt.